# Powershell GUI How can I add column to GridView

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

This is part of a much larger script 1443 lines to be exact. it pulls the username from AD based on first and last name. I need to also have it pull the Office name from AD to help better identify users with same name. I am sure I am just missing something simple.

```
function getacctname {
    $fname = $FirstName.Text
    $lname = $LastName.Text
    Try {
     $User.Text = Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$fname' -and SurName -eq '$lname'" |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'SamAccountName' |
           Out-Gridview -Title 'Windows Logon' -PassThru
           $Email.Text = (Get-ADUser $User.text -Properties mail).mail
}
```

Comment: You mean `Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$fname' -and SurName -eq '$lname'" | Select-Object SamAccountName, EmailAddress | Out-Gridview -Title 'Windows Logon' -PassThru` ?

Comment: No. "Office" is one of the attributes available with the Get-Aduser command. In our AD Office is the City Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Out-GridView` dynamically builds its columns based on the input data you feed to it - so in order to get 3 columns, create an object with 3 properties!

Change the `Select-Object` statement so that it creates an object with properties corresponding to your desired columns and `Out-GridView` takes care of the rest:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$fname' -and SurName -eq '$lname'" -Properties physicalDeliveryOfficeName |
     Select-Object 'SamAccountName',@{Name='Office';Expression={$_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName}} |
     Out-Gridview -Title 'Windows Logon' -PassThru
```

If the office name is stored in a different attribute, replace the two occurrances of `physicalDeliveryOfficeName` with the ldap display name of the attribute in question

Comment: That is almost perfect. The only issue is that this passes information back to a textbox in the GUI now it when I select the username in the grid it is passing too muct data back to the textbox in the GUI I now get@{SamAccountName=userID; Office=City, State} I only need the User ID to  be passed to the textbox. the City, State is only used to know you are choosing the correct user. this is a global company and we have alot of duplicate names

Comment: Honestly, if you have a GUI anyway I wouldnt use Out-Gridview to select a user, it's clunky. Just create a ListView in your GUI to display choices

Comment: @PCMedicJAX Tack `| Select-Object -Expand SAMAccountName` on right after the `Out-GridView` command to extract just the username for the final assignment :)